# The option Parallelization for Compile

Tags: parallelization, compile

When during the compilation of a function of one argument we use the option `RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}`, the resulting function is automatically threaded over a list of arguments. In that situation, we might try to further speed up the function by using parallel computing. That can be done by using the option `Parallelization`. According to the documentation, it can be used with three settings: `True`, `False` and `Automatic`. The latter is the default.

Let us consider some examples.

```
cl1=Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{res=1,m=n},
  While[ m!=1, res++;m=If[EvenQ[m], Round[m/2], 3m+1]]; res],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->False];

cl2=Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{res=1,m=n},
  While[ m!=1, res++;m=If[EvenQ[m], Round[m/2], 3m+1]]; res],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True];

cl3=Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{res=1,m=n},
  While[ m!=1, res++;m=If[EvenQ[m], Round[m/2], 3m+1]]; res],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}];

cl1[Range[10^6]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClearSystemCache[];
cl2[Range[10^6]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClearSystemCache[];
cl3[Range[10^6]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
{8.9881,Null}
{2.53443,Null}
{2.53158,Null}
*)
```

This is more or less as I expected it to be. My computer has `$ProcessorCount=4`, so we gain a factor more than 3, also in last case, where I did not explicitely ask for parallelization.

The next very similar examples show a different behaviour:

```
f1=Compile[{x}, Module[{z=x}, Log[1+z^2]],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->False];

f2=Compile[{x}, Module[{z=x}, Log[1+z^2]],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True];

f3=Compile[{x}, Module[{z=x}, Log[1+z^2]],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}];

lst=RandomReal[{0,1}, {3 10^7}];
f1[lst]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClearSystemCache[];
f2[lst]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClearSystemCache[];
f3[lst]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
{1.79425,Null}
{1.25997,Null}
{1.90643,Null}
*)
```

Here the setting `True` for `Parallelization` is only slightly faster than the setting `False` and the default setting `Automatic` is slightly slower than the setting `False`.

```
g1=Compile[{{n, _Integer}},Module[{z=n}, 1+z^2],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->False];

g2=Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{z=n}, 1+z^2],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True];

g3=Compile[{{n, _Integer}},Module[{z=n}, 1+z^2],
  RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}];

lst=RandomInteger[{0,10^6}, {5 10^7}];
g1[lst]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClearSystemCache[];
g2[lst]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClearSystemCache[];
g3[lst]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
{1.77167,Null}
{1.92518,Null}
{1.79436,Null}
*)
```

Now the setting `True` seems to be slower than the setting `False`, and the setting `Automatic` is not faster than the setting `False`.

So the default setting `Automatic` does not always result in the fastest computation. Very likely, that is not the intended behaviour. How can we avoid this? I am aware of the fact that parallel computations may have a considerable overhead, so that they indeed can be slower than the unparallelized computation. But the three examples that I presented here are almost identical. So what gives these differences?

Comment: My guess would be that in your first example, the significant speedup is due to the presence of operations like loops, increments / indexing. In the second and third cases, your code (like `1+z^2`) is already a `Listable` function internally, so to speak. So, even without using `Compile`, it is already pretty optimal (IIRC, a number of built-in `Listable` functions thread / parallelize automatically). So, the compilation step in those examples doesn't bring much w.r.t. internal optimizations, and sometimes may even slow things down a bit.

Comment: @Leonid. It was exactly for this reason that I used the Module construction. That was and is a little bit stupid, for even with the Module the argument of Compile in my last two examples is de facto Listable. It is a nice idea that the inconsistent behaviour of the option Parallelization could have to do with the automatic parallelization of essentially listable functions.

Comment: if an option like that with a default `Automatic` exists, what you see is what I would expect: it is difficult if not impossible to decide whether parallelization on an arbitrary system for an arbitrary piece of code will speed up the calculation or not. So the best that `Automatic` can do is to make some heuristic assumptions and use these for the decision. That sometimes makes the right decision, sometimes not. For the cases where it does make wrong decisions there is the possibility to make explicit choices. Why do you think you can expect more than that?

Comment: @Albert. Thank you for your clear explanation what to expect from an option setting Automatic. Having read your comment, I regret some of my formulations. However, my final formulation: why do three almost identical examples give such a differet behaviour with respect to the option Parallelization, is my real question. Leonid kindly pointed out that the three examples are not so identical as I thougt: the last two are esssentially listable and the first one is not.

Comment: No need to be sorry for your formulations. I think one has to keep in mind that we are talking about a speed optimization here so if making the right decision is more expensive than what you can possibly gain you are better off to risk a wrong decision. Maybe they just look at something very simple like depth of expression or some measure of complexity of the body expression. I consider it positive that they get the first case with the most speed gain right, for the other two the difference is less pronounced, so a bad decision for them seems less problematic -- and might be more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I have no insight in what Mathematica really is doing here, but with the default setting `Automatic` Mathematica needs to make a decision whether or not the code that is compiled can be expected to run faster when parallelized or not. There are some booundary conditions which seem to make that decision quite difficult if not impossible:

- as always parallelization has costs in form of overhead, so it is not always better to parallelize. Typically more work per item will have a better chance for speed gain.
- speed gain of parallelization depends on various aspects of OS and its settings and of hardware configuration (speed of processors, interconnects, caches,...) and -- with newer processors -- even on current state of the hardware like core temperatures which influence clock speeds.
- the code needs to make that decision in advance, it is also usually dangerous to try to run a downsized example in order to see which case works better as the size of the problem matters.

Of course one could try to make the decision take as many of these boundary conditions into account as possible. But it will still remain the risk of getting it wrong and of course it might become more expensive to make that decision than to actually run the code. So a reasonable choice seems to find some simple criterion to make that decision, adjust it to get it "mostly right" and live with the fact that in some cases the heuristics will make the wrong decision. For these cases, the user can overwrite the heuristics and with a reasonable criterion one will mostly get those cases wrong where the difference isn't too large.

Considering this, a working hypothesis would be that ist might be something as simple as the `LeafCount` of the body expression which might be used to make that decision. (`LeafCount` is one possible measure of complexity also used e.g. as the default for `ComplexityFunction` in `Simplify`). In fact on my computer when compiling the two expressions:

```
Module[{z = x}, Sin@Log[1 + z^2] + Cos@z]
Module[{z = x}, Sin@Log[1 + z^2] + 2*z]
```

where the former has `LeafCount` 15 and the latter has 16, the former will not be parallelized while the latter will be. If you look at your examples, you will find that they would also fit that pattern (first example has `LeafCount` 34 > 15 and is parallelized, second has `LeafCount` 11 < 15, not parallelized and the third has `LeafCount` 10 < 15, also not parallelized).

Again, this is just a hypotheses, I could imagine that something slightly (but probably not much) more advanced is going on behind the scenes...

Some other conclusions: if a similar approach was taken, one has to make some adjustment (e.g. why is the limit 15 ?) and that was probably done with experiments on hardware when that code was introduced. The best fit for newer hardware might be a different number. As your example shows Mathematica makes the right decision in the case where the difference is large (first example) but makes the wrong decision in the two examples where the difference is less pronounced. To me that looks alright, although it looks like the limit (whatever it really is) might need some adjustment, at least on the OPs computer.

Comment: This looks pretty convincing. Only some small comments. (1) Your LeafCount is with the unevalated argument to be compiled. I think it is better to use the evaluated argument.  Sin[Log[1+x^2]]+2 x+1 has a leafcount of 12 and is parallelized. (2) On my system, Module[{z=x},Sin[Log[1+z^2]]+2 z] is not parallelized, but Module[{z=x},Sin[Log[1+z^2]]+2 z +1] (see (1)) is. (3) These two examples also show that 'listability', as in @Leonid's comment,  is not the explanation. The two  functions are almost identical. Both are de facto listable but one is parallized and the other is not.

Comment: @FredSimons: You are right, I was using the `LeafCount` of the unevaluated argument and your example shows that that seems not to be exactly what is used inside. I'm not really surprised that it isn't, I just tried to illustrate what in principle might go on in that decision and the the behavior you have seen seems to be about what one could expect. What really is used to make that decision is something only WRI internals could answer...