# What do the Compile options" RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True" mean?

Tags: parallelization, compile

I am confused about what Compile's Listable and Parallelization options do.

(edit: This post is relevant: [stack exchange "The option parallelization  for compile"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127782/the-option-parallelization-for-compile?rq=1))

My initial assumption was that Listable was creating multiple threads on a single core. I have 10 cores on my machine.  Here is an example.

Parallelization is True:

```
  cfParallelizationTrue = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sin[Sqrt[Abs[x]]],
      CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
      RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]

With[{rr = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]},
 RepeatedTiming[cfParallelizationTrue[rr];]]
(*{0.000055932556, Null}*)
```

Parallelization is False

```
cfParallelizationFalse = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sin[Sqrt[Abs[x]]],
  CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> False]

With[{rr = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]},
 RepeatedTiming[cfParallelizationFalse[rr];]]
(*{0.000041559204, Null}*)
```

Parallelization->False gives about 25% speed up.  I don't know why.

Does Parallelization mean that it the computation can use multiple kernels?

```
LaunchKernels[];
$KernelCount
(*10*)
With[{rr = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]},
 RepeatedTiming[
  ParallelTable[cfParallelizationTrue[rr];, {i, 1, $KernelCount}]]
 ]
(*0.0042045547*)
```

If there were no overhead for parallel, this should be about the same as running it once on a single core.

```
With[{rr = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]},
 RepeatedTiming[
  ParallelTable[cfParallelizationFalse[rr];, {i, 1, $KernelCount}]]
 ]
(*0.0041659531*)
```

There seems to be no benefit in any case for using multiple kernels.

Is this because each call to cfParallelizationFalse[rr] is using all my cores because cfParallelizationFalse has Listable->True even though there is only one kernel??

And, cfParallelizationTrue[rr] in a ParallelTable is using all the kernels, but they are running 10 times slower because each Kernel's core is busy ??

Comment: Listable means the function is threaded over lists. Compiled functions are different from Regular Listsble functions in that the threading depends on the argument type. A compiled function with a vector argument will thread down to vectors; a regular functions always threads down to scalars

Comment: Parallelization in the WVM which requires Listable has minimal overhead or at least optimized overhead, I believe. Due to restricted data types and data sharing.

Comment: Parallelizing a parallelized process sounds like compressing a compressed file— the result is almost always worse. But I don’t know that about parallelization

Comment: I think part of my confusion stems from not understanding what a multi-threaded process on a single core does, as opposed to multi-threaded processes on multiple cores.  I was under the assumption that each launched kernel was attached to one of the cores—and each of those cores could be multi-threaded.  Perhaps Threadable in the WL has nothing to do with running a multi-thread process.

Comment: (`Thread[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and process thread are unrelated concepts. `Listable` is related to the first and not the second. -- Parallelization in the WVM is handled without launching separate kernels, unlike `ParallelTable[]` and other `Parallel*` functions. I don't believe kernels are attached to specific cores, but there's usually little point in having more kernels than cores. I think the scheduling of processes is left to the OS, but that's my assumption.